# Dygraphs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, dygraphs

I am trying to use a Dygraph in my Reactjs web application but I am unable to implement it. I am completely new with Dygraphs. I tried this demo graph but unable to do it. Website also provides the details regarding HTML and JS based graphs. I am facing issues to integrate it in my React App. Also, I am not getting how to pass data to the graph. Kindly help with this. Thank you for your help !

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';
import 'dygraphs/dist/dygraph.min.css'

class DyGraph extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const g = new Dygraph('graph',
        `Date,A,B
    2016/01/01,10,20
    2016/07/01,20,10
    2016/12/31,40,30
    `, {
        title: 'Pressure Transient(s)',
        titleHeight: 32,
        ylabel: 'Pressure (meters)',
        xlabel: 'Time',
        gridLineWidth: '0.1',
        width: 700,
        height: 300,
        connectSeparatedPoints: true,
        axes: { "x": { "axisLabelFontSize": 9 }, "y": { "axisLabelFontSize": 9 } },
        labels: ['Date', 'Tampines Ave10 (Stn 40)'],

    });
}

render() {
    return <div id="graph"></div>;
}
}

export default DyGraph;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Constructing dygraph with a non-existent div!
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
new DyGraph
D:/themesdemo/src/components/DyGraph/index.js:17
14 |        //     { name: 'Group D', value: 200 },
15 |        // ];
16 | 
> 17 |        const g = new Dygraph('graph',
   | ^  18 |            `Date,A,B
19 |        2016/01/01,10,20
20 |        2016/07/01,20,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `<div>` doesn't exist in the DOM until after the component mounts (the sequence is `constructor` then `render` then `componentDidMount`). If you try creating the graph in `componentDidMount`, you'll have better luck:

```js
class DyGraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="graph"></div>;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const g = new Dygraph('graph', `...`, { /* ... */ });
  }
}
```

If you have more than one chart on the page, you'll need to use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

There is also a [`react-dygraphs`](https://github.com/motiz88/react-dygraphs#readme) library you could try, though it hasn't been updated in a few years now.